# GCP table creation taking a long time to create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We're running into an issue where GCP takes a long time to create a table. Our instance is using 1 node and the database is currently at 23.73% CPU, 74.99MB size and has already 106 tables.

I'm sure we're not hitting the limits yet as the max no. of table is 2048.

Have anyone encountered this issue and possible solution? Thanks!

More info:
The time it takes to complete usually takes more than 2 hours and it happens from time to time when creating multiple tables. When all the tables completely created, the CPU utilization reads at 330%

And now event the create index takes too long to complete.

Comment: I work on the Cloud Spanner team. This isn't expected behavior. Could you open an issue as described here - https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/support#file-feature-requests-and-bug-reports - and we can follow up to find out what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, just opened an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71962746